# Android studio does not recognize phone

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-10, driver, device

I am new to android development and am trying to run a test app on my android phone. But it will not detect my device when I click "run". I have tried to go through the OEM USB driver installation but it always says "Windows has determined that the best driver for this device is already installed. There may be better drivers on Windows Update or on the device manufacturer's website." When I unclick "Include subfolders" it says "The location you specified does not contain any driver package (.INF) files." I have tried other methods through device manager of installing OEM USB driver software, both selecting the directory C:\Users\My name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\usb_driver and the one where I installed the samsung usb driver. I have been attempting to follow this link: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb which is where android studio sent me.

Comment: Yes, I have enabled USB debugging, developer options, and have tried switching to PTP from MTP and restarting my device. My device never shows up in the popup after I click "run", and it says it doesn't detect target device when I set the target to a usb device. But, I did get it working yesterday, although I am not sure how. It appeared for a few seconds in the popup and I downloaded the app although it was broken and didn't run. I don't recall doing anything beforehand except messing around with the AVD as an alternative.

Comment: I was able to get the popup asking for permission to be debugged after turning off USB debugging and revoking previous debugging authorizations, and then turning off Twilight on my phone, but my device still doesn't appear after a restart of Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Lets try the most obvious one. Have you enabled usb debugging on your phone yet? When I was starting android this has happened to me. If not enable it through your phone's Settings> Developer Options> Usb Debugging.

If the Developer options is not yet shown, tap the Build Number seven times to show it.

Build number is mostly found on About> Software Information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable USB debugging in your device too, refer this link for process https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options